# on selection of checkbox display textarea. if it's not selected textarea value should empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I created page with 2 checkbox, submit and reset button as attached image

[image]

If i click on radio buttons it will show hidden text area's.

[image]

If I select both checkboxes and click on submit it will work fine. But if I click on only one of the checkboxes and click on submit it won't work.

Could you please help me how to submit the query with selecting only one checkbox?

My `request_to_approve.php` code is

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkValue()
{

if(document.getElementById("reject").checked == true)
 {
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo1').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo2').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo3').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo4').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo5').style.display='block';

 }
else
 {
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo1').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo2').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo3').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo4').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('xtraInfo5').style.display='none';
 }
}

function checkswcr()
{

if(document.getElementById("swcr").checked == true)
 {
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo1').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo2').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo3').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo4').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo5').style.display='block';

 }
else
 {
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo1').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo2').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo3').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo4').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('swcrInfo5').style.display='none';
 }
}

function checkother()
{

if(document.getElementById("other").checked == true)
 {
   document.getElementById('otherInfo').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('otherInfo1').style.display='block';
        if(document.getElementById("reject").checked == false)
                {
   document.getElementById('otherInfo2').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('otherInfo3').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('otherInfo4').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('otherInfo5').style.display='block';
                }

 }
else
 {
   document.getElementById('otherInfo').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('otherInfo1').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('otherInfo2').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('otherInfo3').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('otherInfo4').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('otherInfo5').style.display='none';
 }
}

</script>

<table id="structure">
         <tr>
                <td id="page">
                <body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) )
        {
        $pronto = $_POST['pronto'];
        $fatal = $_POST['fatal'];
        $medi = $_POST['medi'];
        $neu = $_POST['neu'];
        $swcr = $_POST['swcr'];
        print_r($pronto);
        print_r($fatal);
        print_r($medi);
        print_r($neu);
        print_r($swcr);
        }
?>
</br>
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">

<html>
        <table width="100%" align="left" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                <form name = "Register" method = "post" action = "request_to_approve.php">

       <tr>

                <td>
                PR: <input type='checkbox' name='reject' id='reject' value='Rejected' onClick="checkValue()" />
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td align="left">
  <div id="xtraInfo1" style="text-align:left; display:none; font-weight:bold;">
    PRONTO Details: </div></td>
                <td>
  <div id="xtraInfo" style="text-align:left; display:none; font-weight:bold;">
    <textarea  id="pronto" width="900" style="width: 650px;  resize:vertical;" name="pronto" required><?php if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) { print_r($_POST['rejectdt']); }?></textarea>
  </div>
                </td>
        </tr>

       <tr>
                <td>
                <div id="xtraInfo2" style="text-align:left; display:none; font-weight:bold;">Review Comments :</div></td>
                <td>

                <table>
                <tr>
                        <td  align="center">   <div id="xtraInfo3" style="text-align:left; display:none; font-weight:bold;">Fatal :- </br>
                        <textarea id="fatal" class="wmd-input processed" name="fatal" type="file" cols="31" rows="5" tabindex="50" data-min-length="" wrap=physical required></textarea>
                        </div></td>
                <td align="center"> <div id="xtraInfo4" style="text-align:left; display:none; font-weight:bold;">Medium :- </br>
                        <textarea id="medi" class="wmd-input processed" name="medi" type="file" cols="31" rows="5" tabindex="50" data-min-length="" wrap=physical required></textarea>
                                        </div></td>
                <td align="center"> <div id="xtraInfo5" style="text-align:left; display:none; font-weight:bold;">Neutral :- </br>
                        <textarea id="neu" class="wmd-input processed" name="neu" type="file" cols="31" rows="5" tabindex="50" data-min-length="" wrap=physical required></textarea>
                                        </div></td>

                </tr>
                </table>
        </tr>

       <tr>

                <td>
                SWCR/Feature : <input type='checkbox' name='swcr' id='swcr' value='swcr' onClick="checkswcr()" />
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td align="left">
  <div id="swcrInfo1" style="text-align:left; display:none; font-weight:bold;">
    SWCR/Feature/Backlog Details: </div></td>
                <td>
  <div id="swcrInfo" style="text-align:left; display:none; font-weight:bold;">
    <textarea  id="swcr" width="900" style="width: 650px;  resize:vertical;" name="swcr" required><?php if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) { print_r($_POST['swcr']); } ?></textarea>
  </div>
                </td>
        </tr>


<tr><td>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</td></tr>
        </form>
        </table>
        </table>
</html>
```

Could anyone please help me on this

Comment: Can you please explain what you want exactly because some where in your question you have mentioned as radio button and some where as check box but no radio button is there.

Comment: @Alankar More: Without selecting checkbox PR (only selecting SWCR checkbox) i want to submit the query. is it possible?

Comment: yes it is but on click on SWCR the text box should be open and on click of 
PR it should get hide. is that you want?

Comment: @Alankar More: No. If i click on PR it will open text area then i fill the data in text area after that i wont' click on SWCR and if i click on submit button it won't work. my code will only work if i click on both PR and SWCR button. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Please lookup jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkswcr(){   
        var swcrInfo = document.getElementById('swcrInfo');    
        swcrInfo.style.display == 'block' ? swcrInfo.style.display = 'none' : swcrInfo.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2fm4277h/)

Answer (score -1):

okay make a hidden field like a number, store a value on first checkbox click..attach your desired function to it. on second checkbox click store a different value and the function and if both the checkboxes have been clicked store the third value in the same hidden field. the value of the hidden field will indicate exactly what to do with the click..hope it should work